# Transition probability of a Markov Chain (Paper)

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, birth-death-process

I've been checking out this paper and I got stuck.  I want to know how to calculate the transition probability of a birth and death Markov process. To understand the logic of the paper and how they get to the result, and how differential equations get involved in the procedure.

This is the link of the paper if you need to check it out http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0895717711005541

Comment: The logic of the paper is spelt out pretty clearly: "Thus the forward Kolmogorov differential equations can be obtained as follows [12]:", where [12] is a leisurely textbook explaining the forward Kolmogorov differential equation using lots of examples of similar processes.